# Why do the following netstat, ps, and auth.log have such output?

Tags: server, ssh, connection, webserver, logs

I seem to be getting a lot of different connections (ssh) on this Ubuntu server I am sshed into. Are these just brute force attempts?

When running `netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'` why do I get at end of each line "root@p" and "[accep" respectively?

Furthermore, when running `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | tail -20` I seem to get a lot of different "invalid users". Why is that so?
Lastly, `ps auxwww | grep sshd:` outputs two "[accepted]". Why is that so?

Thank you. The output of the command's can be seen below -->

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2qNQ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMByp.png

Update:

Another interesting thing happened now. I ran  `netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd'` again and an IP in the form "103.100.xxxx" from Hong Kong apparently was listed. I had then run  `cat /var/log/auth.log | tail -100` and  gotten the following

```
Feb 16 17:58:25 838396123831 sshd[227710]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.100.210.xxx  user=root
Feb 16 17:58:26 838396123831 sshd[227708]: Received disconnect from 103.136.xxxxp ort 33268:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 16 17:58:26 838396123831 sshd[227708]: Disconnected from invalid user hero 103.136.xxxx port 33268 [preauth]
Feb 16 17:58:27 838396123831 sshd[227710]: Failed password for root from 103.100.xxxx port 40810 ssh2
Feb 16 17:58:27 838396123831 sshd[227710]: Received disconnect from 103.100.xxxx port 40810:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Feb 16 17:58:27 838396123831 sshd[227710]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 103.100.xxxx port 40810 [preauth]
```

Then I ran `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | tail -20` and spotted `Feb 16 18:00:42 838396123831 sshd[227760]: Failed password for invalid user ircbot from 103.136.xxxxx port 47546 ssh2`

I then run `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | tail -100` and see

```
Feb 16 17:53:24 838396123831 sshd[227596]: Failed password for root from 103.136.xxxx port 33470 ssh2
Feb 16 17:55:57 838396123831 sshd[227652]: Failed password for root from 103.136.xxxxx port 47406 ssh2

Feb 16 17:58:24 838396123831 sshd[227708]: Failed password for invalid user hero from 103.136.xxxxx port 33268 ssh2
Feb 16 18:00:42 838396123831 sshd[227760]: Failed password for invalid user ircbot from 103.136.xxxxx port 47546 ssh2
```

What does this mean? What is happening? Was or is any other person managed to log in to the server via ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are brute force attacks. Anybody with an externally facing device will, almost immediately, be subjected to these type of attacks.

No, I do not think you have actually been compromised. The `ESTABLISHED` connection you observed was just an in progress attempt. Don't confuse an `ESTABLISHED` tcp connection with a successful SSH login, they are not the same.

I am assuming the actual SSH connection is you.

Consider changing your SSH port away from the default port 22 and/or implementing a 'bad guy' detector. Many recommend fail2ban. I use the recent module in iptables. The trick with China is to block an entire sub-net, not just the attacking IP, because they have gotten clever and merely switch to another IP once blocked. Example iptables rule segment, somewhat out of context:

```
# Dynamic Badguy List. Detect and DROP Bad IPs that do password attacks on SSH.
# Once they are on the BADGUY list then DROP all packets from them.
# Sometimes make the lock time very long. Typically to try to get rid of coordinated attacks from China.
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m recent --mask $BIT_MASK --update --hitcount 3 --seconds 90000 --name BADGUY_SSH -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH BAD:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m recent --mask $BIT_MASK --update --hitcount 3 --seconds 90000 --name BADGUY_SSH -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --mask $BIT_MASK --set --name BADGUY_SSH -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks. So the "ESTABLISHED" in the netstat command output does not mean another person has successfully sshd but that it was an in progress attempt?

Comment: Yes. `ESTABLISHED` in this context only means the low level tcp (Transport Control Protocol) that a `SYN` packet has been received and a `SYN,ACK` sent back, possibly another `ACK` creating an `ESTABLISHED` tcp connection. A shorter way to say it is that the handshaking has been done to create a connection. Thereafter things can happen at a higher level, in your case try to login, which fails.

Comment: Thanks :). Have a good day!